# Render js.erb for XHR request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to set rails to render .js.erb files by default for xhr requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then update your rails.js to the latest from here https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs and set the default request header for ajax calls with this:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a very recent commit for reference: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/commit/fbbefa0773d791d3a67b7a3bb971c10ca750131b

Comment: This seems like correct solution, but this stil did not set accept header

Comment: Did you update rails.js from github? For me it works correctly.

Comment: for remote links it works, but for remote forms it still does not.

Comment: Normal scaffold and with this change `<%= form_for(@car, :remote => true) do |f| %>`. works correctly for me. Could you add minimal example of what doesn't work to your question?

Comment: BeforeSend function does not get called when submitting remote forms. still debugging, wierd.